# Does db_query and db_insert escape input values? prevent sql injection?

Tags: 7, database

I've been reading through the documentation, but I feel like it's always a little bit vague on this, perhaps I'm missing something.

```
function foomodule_my_hook_menu_callback($unescapedUserInputString) {
    $sql = "select name from {foo_table} where bar=:inputString";
    $result = db_query($sql, array(':inputString' => $unescapedUserInputString));
}
```

Is the above code vulnerable to an SQL injection attack? Or will `:inputString` get appropriately escaped to make it safe for SQL? (I know I need to sanitize it for proper values in my implementation, but I'm just referring to the SQL safety)

What about with db_insert()?

```
$insert_id = db_insert('foo_table')
                ->fields(array(
                    'name' => $unescapedUserInputString,
                ))
                ->execute();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [is db_insert secure?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26816/is-db-insert-secure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

these functions are abstractions on top of php's PDO library. They are essentially `prepared sql statements` ... passed values to the query are safe from SQL-injection.

Feel free to jump into the [PHP PDO Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

EDIT:

eg,

> Many of the more mature databases support the concept of prepared
>   statements. What are they? They can be thought of as a kind of
>   compiled template for the SQL that an application wants to run, that
>   can be customized using variable parameters. Prepared statements offer
>   two major benefits:
>
> The query only needs to be parsed (or prepared) once, but can be
>   executed multiple times with the same or different parameters. When
>   the query is prepared, the database will analyze, compile and optimize
>   its plan for executing the query. For complex queries this process can
>   take up enough time that it will noticeably slow down an application
>   if there is a need to repeat the same query many times with different
>   parameters. By using a prepared statement the application avoids
>   repeating the analyze/compile/optimize cycle. This means that prepared
>   statements use fewer resources and thus run faster.
>
> The parameters to
>   prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the driver automatically
>   handles this. If an application exclusively uses prepared statements,
>   the developer can be sure that no SQL injection will occur (however,
>   if other portions of the query are being built up with unescaped
>   input, SQL injection is still possible).

Comment: Even the db_query() where I'm passing it a custom SQL statement? Just want to be VERY sure. :)

Comment: YES. That's the point of placeholders.